# How to use SafeAreaView for Android notch devices?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an app with React Native and I'm testing with my OnePlus 6 and it has a notch. The SafeAreaView is a solution for the iPhone X but for Android, it seems there is no solution.

How to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Looks like it is not supported https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17371 Advice is to go ask on that GitHub or don't use React-native.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A work around I had to use recently:

GlobalStyles.js:

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
export default StyleSheet.create({
    droidSafeArea: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: npLBlue,
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 25 : 0
    },
});
```

It is applied like so:

App.js

```
import GlobalStyles from './GlobalStyles';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={GlobalStyles.droidSafeArea}>
          //More controls and such
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

You'll probably need to adjust it a bit to fit whatever screen you're working on, but this got my header just below the icon strip at the top.

Comment: Thanks your code will be helpful however if we're on android but we have no notch, we will a space at the top of the screen

Comment: @ThomasDesdoits I'm currently testings on a Moto E4 Plus, that doesn't have a notch and my header was still showing up under the bar at the top with the wifi signal and carrier info. I had to do this to push it down out of that. I can't get it to run in a VM to test other phone types, but I would assume it would act the same on any android device. Do you not get that behavior on your test device?

Comment: actually i can' t it test on another phone, in my case i'm using a paddingtop of 30, i don't think it is possible but the better solution will be te get the status bar height with "StatusBar.currentHeight"

Comment: @ThomasDesdoits Oh absolutely if you can get the measurement off some property that would be ideal. I couldn't find one and just had to hardcode :(

Comment: The newest version of `react-native-device-info` has a function for this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#hasNotch

Comment: The GlobalStyle idea is good. by the way, it works good but in my android phone, 25 padding is not enough. but in another phone 25 is good. is there any function to get the status bar height?

Comment: @SunnySultan when I originally wrote this there wasn't. But some of the other answers seem to suggest there's a "StatusBar.currentHeight" variable these days that you might be able to use. I haven't worked on the code around this in a while so I don't know if that's a thing for all androids of those posters specific versions.

Comment: Thanks, saved the day.

Answer (score 202):

Do something like

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({
  AndroidSafeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  }
});
```

And then In your App.js

```
import SafeViewAndroid from "./components/SafeViewAndroid";

 <SafeAreaView style={SafeViewAndroid.AndroidSafeArea}>
          <Layout screenProps={{ navigation: this.props.navigation }} /> //OR whatever you want to render
        </SafeAreaView>
```

This should work good as get height will take care of the knotch in android device by calculating the statusBar height and it will arrange accordingly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it takes uses the StatusBar.currentHeight instead of a arbitrary height. Note that the status bar height may vary.

Comment: Awesome. Works on my OnePlus 7 pro. This is the correct one and not using external package.

Comment: This works, I've just added it as the part of the style to my SafeAreaView in my ScreenContainer component that I use for all screens.

Comment: On the device I'm currently using, this doesn't appear to work correctly. It does work if I remove the line `paddingTop`. In order words, to not set any padding. I don't know why this is the case. It could be because I have this in my root component: `<StatusBar barStyle={"dark-content"} />`

Answer (score 38):

Late 2020 answer: For anyone stumbling across this issue themselves, they have added support for this.

Follow [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/?redirected) documentation page

Comment: If only you posted this one day earlier (when I implemented the SafeViewAndroid to my entire UI). Regardless, thanks for pointing this out. Much more elegant this way.

Comment: Please could you add some detail and code example, I am not sure to see how the linked document solves this issue

Comment: A much a simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You could also create helper component with this style applied right away like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.AndroidSafeArea} {...props} >
    {props.children}
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  AndroidSafeArea: {
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  }
});
```

Make note that I also deleted unnecessary styles which breaks natural behavior of SafeAreaView which in my case broke styling.

As for use you simply use it like normal SafeAreaView:

```
import React from 'react';
import SafeAreaView from "src/Components/SafeAreaView";

render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
          // Rest of your app
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how do styles break SafeAreaView?  I'm curious to know so I don't run into any issues with the app I'm launching!

Answer (score 13):

for more consistency import:

```
import { Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";
```

and then use it like so:

```
paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
```

Answer (score 9):

if you're seeing this in 2020 and you also need the web support with the Android and iOS, type this in your terminal.
`expo install react-native-safe-area-context`
this will install the updated safe area context.
Then import the following stuffs into your `app.js`

`import { SafeAreaView, SafeAreaProvider} from "react-native-safe-area-context";`

add `<SafeAreaProvider>` before all the tags in your main function in `app.js`, also remember to close it at the end.
and finally, instead of `view`, add `SafeAreaView`.
Read more at the official expo website : [SafeAreaContext](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/?redirected)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it works for both Android and IOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is currently the best or easiest way to implement SafeAreaView on Android and ios for both vanilla RN and Expo.

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works well in 2023 and it is the cleanest solution: don't forget to run: npm i react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score 5):

Although the docs says it is relevant only for iOS, when I used React's SafeAreaView it acted differently on different screens on Android.

I managed to fix the problem by implementing my version of SafeAreaView:

```
import React from "react";
import { Platform, View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { GeneralStyle } from "../styles";

export function SaferAreaView({ children }) {
  if (Platform.OS == "ios") {
    return <SaferAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>{children}</SaferAreaView>;
  }
  if (Platform.OS == "android") {
    return <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight}}>{children}</View>;
  }
}
```

This was tested on an old device (with hardware navigation) and new notch devices (with software navigation) - different screen sizes.

Answer (score 4):

1 - expo install expo-constants

2- and do like this for example

```html
import React from "react";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";

export default function HeaderTabs({ style }) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.screen, style]}>
            <View style={[styles.view, style]}>
                <Text>Hello this is status bar</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flex: 1,
    },
    view: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I used `StatusBar` from `react-native` instead of `expo-status-bar` and this worked for me on my OnePlus as well as other Android devices.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `StatusBar` component which comes with the `react-native` package or the `expo-status-bar` package (the both have the same component name, and almost the same api).

```
export default App(){ // this is your root component
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar translucent={false} />
      // ... the rest of your code
    </View>
  )
}
```

> Just make sure you've set the `translucent` prop to **false**:-
>
> - in expo status bar, it's true by default. -> so set it to false.
> - in react native, it's set to false by default. so no changes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Platform API, you can use expo constants.

```
npm i expo-constants
```

then import it in your component as

```
import Constants from "expo-constants"
```

and then in the styles you can use it like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
} });
```

To see all the properties of Constants console log it you will find some more useful things.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same problem. I solved this using this lib [React Native Status Bar Height](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height), and I recommend because it´s a piece of cake to use. 
And if you are using style-components you can add the `getStatusBarHeight()` on your styles.js like I did on the example below:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import { getStatusBarHeight} from 'react-native-status-bar-height';

export const Background = styled.View`
 flex:1;
 background:#131313;
 margin-top: ${getStatusBarHeight()};
```

`

Answer (score 2):

to solve this problem you can use `react-native-safe-area-context` please refer to [this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/) link for detailed information.

what you need to do is first install the package using

`npx expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

then after importing `SafeAreaView` you can use it without any more styling like this

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    
function SomeComponent() {
   return (
     <SafeAreaView>
       <View />
     </SafeAreaView>
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `SafeAreaView` [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) was told:

> It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later.

So now I definitely use it in my project but I use `Platform` to recognize device platform and for Android, I make a manual safe area for the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `react-native-device-info` for device info and apply styling also with a notch

Answer (score 1):

**

- this is working in 2023. import *SafeAreaView* from *'react-native-safe-area-context'*

**

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    export default function App() {
      return (
       <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <yourComponent/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    
        </SafeAreaView>
        
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex : 1,
        backgroundColor:'green',
       
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Expo solution([docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/#setstatusbartranslucenttranslucent) - android only):

```
import { setStatusBarTranslucent } from 'expo-status-bar';
```

Then in the component you can use `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setStatusBarTranslucent(false)
  },[])
```

for iOS you can use the `<SafeAreaView>` component from [react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview).

Answer (score 0):

ENRICO SECCO was right (i cant comment due to my stackoverflow reputation lol)! any safeareaview thingy doesn't work for me as well, so i get around with
`import { getStatusBarHeight} from 'react-native-status-bar-height';`

here how execute it, keep in mind that this is in my `app.js`, where i put all my `stack.navigator` + `bottomtab.navigator`

```js
export default function App() {

//IGNORE ALL OF THIS, JUMP TO THE RETURN() FUNCTION!

  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
        await Font.loadAsync(AntDesign.font);
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'Montserrat-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
          'Montserrat-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
          'Montserrat-Light': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
        });
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    
  //HERE!
    <NavigationContainer> 
      <View  style = {{
        flex: 1, <- TO MAKE IT FULL SCREEN (PLEASE DELETE THIS)
        marginTop: getStatusBarHeight(), <- TO PUSH IT DOWN FROM OFF SCREEN, MINE RAN OFF TO THE TOP LMAO (PLEASE DELETE THIS)
      }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Tabs/>
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Expo is simple setting globally

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "translucent": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me too, but you need to restart the app so expo reread `apps.json` file

Answer (score 0):

This is a work aound. We can set a padding top specifically for android devices.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
 //your code or components
</SafeAreaView>

styles=StyleSheet.create({
 safeArea:{
   flex:1,
   paddingTop : Platform.OS==="android" ? "20%":0,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still out there looking for the solution, this might help you!!

Import the following :

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```

Create a function named SomeComponent like this :

```
function SomeComponent() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

After that use SafeAreaView the way you want to, I used it as this way :

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <HeaderTabs/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Resources :

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/

https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/users/6877799/amerllica

Answer (score 0):

I added like this in styles in `./home.style`

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import {COLORS, SIZES} from "../../constants";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    SafeArea: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0, // Dynamic padding for Android
    }});
```

and the component like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import styles from './home.style';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.SafeArea}>
            <View style={styles.appBarWrapper}>
                <View style={styles.appBar}>
                    <Ionicons name="location-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                    <Text style={styles.location}>Mumbai</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>HOME CONTENT</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 this still being the straightforward way to solve this problem:

what you need to do is first install the package using:

`npx expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

then after importing `SafeAreaView` you can use it without any more styling like this

```js
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    
function SomeComponent() {
   return (
     <SafeAreaView>
       <View />
     </SafeAreaView>
   );
 }
```