# Do i have to make seperate MyComponent.android.js file to use SafeArea

Tags: react-native, safeareaview

I am pretty new to react-native. Whenever i have to make use of `SafeAreaView` I have to make a seperate `.android.js` file for same component without safe area leading to duplication.

Is it possible to conditionally use `SafeAreaView` with `platform.os`?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427630/11212074

Comment: @hongdevelop I went through the thread. I want to know if I use SafeAreaView and run it on android will it behave like plain View?

Comment: SafeAreaView has the same props as regular views. The view shown is the same as the normal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to use SafeAreaView with Conditionally for Platform.OS.
SafeAreaView only applicable on ios, but also work on android.
On my code SafeAreaView work on both OS.
If there is a need only on a particular OS then give condition.

Comment: So if i am running on Android then SafeAreaView will behave like View?

Comment: Yes, when it is on Notch display it adjusts your UI through SafeAreView in both OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. So what I done is that create one component called whatever you want eg. `SafeScrollView.js` and then render conditionally `SafeAreaView` in that component then pass children to that component.

For example :

I have `SafeScrollView.js` like below :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, Platform } from 'react-native';

const SafeScrollView = (props) => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        return (
            <View style={props.style}>
                {props.children}
            </View>
        );
    }
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={props.style}>
            {props.children}
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default SafeScrollView
```

Then use `SafeScrollView` as a component like below :

```js
<SafeScrollView>
     // Your component
</SafeScrollView>
```

Now, In IOS it will render normal `View` component and if device is android it will render `SafeScrollView`.
So, you don't have to create separate file.

Answer (score 0):

SafeAreaView only supports ios. So, you can use conditional statement to you this for particular os.

Comment: I know that and I have already mentioned that i have to make seperate .android.js file. How can i conditionally use <SafeAreaView> in ios and plain <View> in android.