# What is the equivalent of 'SafeAreaView' on android - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Basically, i am creating a react-native app and i wanted that my logo image didn't overlap with the notification/status bar and i didn't want to set a `marginTop` property manually because the size of the notification bar changes on different models of phones, and i found out that if i replaced my `<View/>` component with a `<SafeAreaView/>` component my problem would be solved.

And while it worked great for IOS, it didn't worked at all for android. Of course, after a quick research i found out that this is a IOS only component, and when you try to use it on Android the `<SafeAreaView/>` component returns a regular `<View/>` back.

So, i am trying to find out if there's a component or a workaround that works on android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(React native) How to use SafeAreaView for Android notch devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289587/react-native-how-to-use-safeareaview-for-android-notch-devices)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, status bar height changes from device to device, so you can either import status bar from react-native, or Constants from Expo so you can get the actual status bar height based on the device that is used.

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const statusBarHeight = Constants.statusBarHeight
```

Comment: I'm new to react native, but `Constants.statusBarHeight` looks totally wrong. The height is nothing constant, it heavily depends on the device if there is a notch or not. There is a complex API on native Android to find that out.

Comment: @rekire The Constants library I believe is install-dependent, so the "constants" should update with each install, allowing it to have the right values for the device

Comment: @rekire Constants is expo-constants library. It does not refer to the variable being "constant". It gets the height of the statusBar of the device that the app is being used. So it is dynamic in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using SafeAreaView from the [react-native-safe-area-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context) package. It will take care of both the Android and iOS problems.

```js
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { View } from 'react-native';

export function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-status-bar-height.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height

It´s just install e and create a const to have this value like:
const barHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
and put it on the marginTop value:
<View style = {{ marginTop: barHeight}}>

or if you´re using styled-components you can put on your styles.js

Answer (score 0):

Use `<SafeAreaProvide>` instead by importing  
`import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';`

Answer (score -2):

This is not a case for Android, becuase even if You have full-screen app in Android, there is no possibility to overlap with status bar. The status bar is neither always visible, or can be "dragged down" to be visible, but in both cases,  the status bar is out of the working area of the application.